convolution-deconvolution while maintaining the original image size
I am trying to implement pspnet in tensorflow.
It requires a pooling module which takes in the input, along with several kernel sizes:

does average pooling on the input with the each kernel AveragePooling2D

does a 1x1 convolution, after which UpSampling2D is used


Finally all the different conv-deconv outputs are concatenated together and fed forward
def pyramid_pooling_module(x, pool_sizes):
    pool_outputs = []
    for pool_size in pool_sizes:
        pooled= layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size)(x)
        pooled= layers.Conv2D(512, (1,1), padding='same')(pooled)
        pooled= layers.UpSampling2D(size=pool_size, interpolation='bilinear')(pooled)
        print(pool_size)
        pool_outputs.append(pooled)
    return layers.Concatenate()(pool_outputs)

The inputs would be of the dimension 68, 120
Because of which the kernels used (1x1, 2x2, 3x3, 6x6) would have rounding errors from the average pooling layers for 3x3, 6x6
such that the final pooled outputs for those layers are (66, 120)
I'm not sure how to go about fixing this, should resize my inputs to a size which is exactly divisible by 6x6? is there another way?

The dimensions of the output from AveragePooling2D can differ from the dimensions of the input, since  default value for padding is 'valid'. Maybe setting padding='same' would fix your issue.
